# Help me to Get Bulkifying trigger

Tags: trigger, bulkification

My Trigger is here.  Invoice is custom Object which have Look up relationship with Account.  Help me with bulkifying this Trigger.

```
trigger InvAmountUpdate on Invoice__c (After Update)
{
    for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New)
    {
        Account acc=new Account();
        acc=[Select id,Account_Balance__c From Account Where id =:inv.Account__c];

        if(acc.Account_Balance__c==null)
            acc.Account_Balance__c=0;  

        Invoice__c  invOld=Trigger.oldMap.get(inv.id);
        if(inv.Invoice_Amount__c!=invOld.Invoice_Amount__c)
            acc.Account_Balance__c=acc.Account_Balance__c-invOld.Invoice_Amount__c+inv.Invoice_Amount__c;

    update acc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than asking people to bulkify your code, you should attempt to do it yourself.  Then when you run into problems doing so you can ask specifically what you are having issues with.  There are countless questions out there and guides on how to bulkify and so it's better to learn how to do it yourself.  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code

Comment: @dphil thanks dude,i have implemented bulkified code but posting that may confuse others for that reason only i had asked you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Please make sure NULL check on the invoice fields used in your code!

```
trigger InvAmountUpdate on Invoice__c (After Update)
{
Set<Id> setOfAccountId = new Set<Id>();
List<Account> listOfAccountsToBeUpdated = new List<Account>();
    for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New)
    {
        setOfAccountId.add(inv.Account__c);
    }
    Map<Id,Account> mapOfAccIdToAcc = new Map<Id,Account>([Select id,Account_Balance__c From Account Where id IN:setOfAccountId]);
    for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New)
    {
        if(inv.Invoice_Amount__c!=Trigger.oldMap.get(inv.id).Invoice_Amount__c && mapOfAccToAccBal.containsKey(inv.Account__c))
        {    
            if(mapOfAccToAccBal.get(inv.Account__c).Account_Balance__c == NULL)
                mapOfAccToAccBal.get(inv.Account__c).Account_Balance__c = 0;
            mapOfAccToAccBal.get(inv.Account__c).Account_Balance__c=mapOfAccToAccBal.get(inv.Account__c).Account_Balance__c-invOld.Invoice_Amount__c+inv.Invoice_Amount__c;
            listOfAccountsToBeUpdated.add(mapOfAccToAccBal.get(inv.Account__c));

        }
    }
    update listOfAccountsToBeUpdated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger InvAmountUpdate on Invoice__c (After Update)
{
    // array variable for bulkifying
    Account[] accArray = new List<Account>();
    Set<Id> accIds=new Set<id>();
    for(Invoice__c accId:Trigger.New)
        accIds.Add(accId.Account__c);

    // get the map of accounts. 
    // reason for using `map` is that you will pass accId to get the account information.
    Map<id, Account> accMap = 
           New Map<id, Account>([Select id,Account_Balance__c From Account Where id IN:accIds]);
    for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New)
    {
        Account currentAcc = accMap.get(inv.Account__c);
        if(currentAcc.Account_Balance__c==null)
            currentAcc.Account_Balance__c=0;  

           Invoice__c  invOld=Trigger.oldMap.get(inv.id);
        if(inv.Invoice_Amount__c!=invOld.Invoice_Amount__c)
            currentAcc.Account_Balance__c=currentAcc.Account_Balance__c-invOld.Invoice_Amount__c+inv.Invoice_Amount__c;

    //  update acc;
        accArray.add(currentAcc);
    }
    Update accArray;
}
```

Comment: The code is not **tested** but it should work with few tweaks. Just out of mind. :)